# Right Approach to crawl and identify bad code

Tags: discussion

As much as we try to keep everything in check at all sites, I have a specific area of concern that I want to work on.

A large number of people write code snippets for helping others over at stackexchange sites. Some of them obviously may also contain bad / vulnerable code. For example

```
echo $_GET['input'];
```

is a classic case of XSS.

What would be the right approach if I want to go ahead and identify all such instance and say for instance add a comment stating that this is not a secure code per se.

Initially the idea is to warn people but at one point the idea is to also write secure alternative code. However since I am a single person working on this idea it would make sense to automate most of it and leave some for manual stuff.

I know there is an API but before I start fiddling with it, I wanted to check if this is OK with Stack Exchange or whether there are some guidelines I should be sticking to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you planning to mass comment on questions? If so you shouldn't do that. The questions may be saying something like

> I've written `echo $_GET['input'];` and a security scan says this is vulnerable to XSS, what should I do?

Adding a comment saying this isn't secure is just noise.

So maybe you're planning to mass comment on answers? That's equally problematic. The answer to the above question could be

> Writing `echo $_GET['input'];` is vulnerable because of the following reasons...
>
> - 1 reason 1
> - 2 reason 2
>
> etc.
>
> And you should write `something sensible here` instead

Your comment would be noise there too.

If you're just planning to find questions/answers that you can manually examine (to avoid such false positives) and then manually add a comment if necessary, that's more sensible. You could try to construct a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) to do that.

Comment: I had simmilar thougts that's why wanted to run it through people before doing anything around it. SEDE Query looks like the way to go.